# Subtotal max of visible cells, return text value in row of highest value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm attempting to write a formula to find the most recent date of an inspection in a filtered data set. These inspection dates are in `Sheet1!I6:I16627`. Once the most recent date is identified in the filtered data set (I want to look at visible cells only), I would like to pull the name of the inspection that is associated with the most recent inspection date. Inspection names are stored in `Sheet!R6:R16627`.

I was trying to build a formula using `=Subtotal(104,I6:16627)` but was unable to determine the best watch to write a match formula, or something similar.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: does your date column have duplicates?

Comment: Yes it does. But any time there is a duplicate, the inspection name is going to be the same.

Comment: For example, there can be five inspection reports that occurred on 1/1/17 with the name Inspection_1. Any of those pulled would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

then wrap your Subtotal in an INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX(Sheet!R6:R16627,MATCH(SUBTOTAL(104,Sheet1!I6:I16627),Sheet1!I6:I16627,0))
```

Comment: Scott, you're amazing! Thank you. I'm tried using an Index Match earlier but I guess wasn't grasping throwing the subtotal after the match.

Comment: @Zarfot please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.